# Django Localhost Issue

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm new on Django web framework and when I run my app with simple start setup, trying to connect localhost server http://127.0.0.1:8000/ through PyCharm. However I get this error with that output:

> System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
>
> You have 14 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
>   Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
>   March 14, 2018 - 13:56:59
>   Django version 2.0.3, using settings 'mysite.settings'
>   Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
>   Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 1: invalid start byte

Also I tried to connect over cmd with 0.0.0.0:8000 definition and with my current ip. Even so I couldn't reach interface. Could you help or tell me how can I overcome that issue ? Any help is appreciated.

> SOLVED : I changed my pc name to form 'UTC-8' and it did work. Thanks for all comment.

Comment: can you show your settings and url files?

Comment: That's not web interface issue, it's problem with character encoding. Do you have a fuller error log?

Comment: Beyond that, did you run "python manage.py migrate"?

Answer (score 2):

You have created models but not migrated them.
To get started first run this command

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Once migrations is done, restart your server.